# How to define nested arrays using zircote/swagger-php

Tags: nested, swagger-ui, swagger-php

I generated the array below in PHP and now don't know how to define it using zircote/swagger-php, I would be very grateful if you could help me.

#### PHP array.

```php
$arr = [
   ['name' => 'foo', 'age' => 1],
   ['name' => 'bar', 'age' => 2],
];

echo json_encode(['data' => $arr]);
```

#### swagger document.

```php
     *     @OA\Response(response=200, description="successful operation",
     *         @OA\JsonContent(
     *              @OA\Property(property="data", type="array", @OA\Items(
     *                   @OA\Property(type="array", @OA\Items(
     *                      @OA\Property(property="name", type="string", example="foo"),
     *                      @OA\Property(property="age", type="integer", example="12"),
     *                  ))
     *             ))
     *         )
     *     ),
```

#### result in swagger ui.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "age": "integer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One too many `Items`?

Try

```
/**
 * @OA\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     @OA\JsonContent(
 *         type="array",
 *         @OA\Items(
 *             type="object",
 *             @OA\Property(type="string", property="name", example="Fred"),
 *             @OA\Property(type="int", property="age", example="52")
 *         )
 *     )
 * )
```